# What are the current research directions in the geometric theory of dynamical systems?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

By geometric theory of dynamical systems, I mean the kind found in [the book by Palis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461257059), or papers like [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.13149). In other words, dynamics on manifolds, but not specifically hyperbolic dynamical systems.

What are some recommended papers, survey articles, lecture notes, or books to read to explore this topic further? I really like this flavour of dynamics and would like to know what the modern research directions/questions are.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the book by Bonatti, Diaz and Viana: "Dynamics beyond uniform hyperbolicity' can give you a nice overview of one possible point of view. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b138174

The book by Katok-Hasselblatt and their Handbook contains a lot of other points of view.

Comment: Thank you! The book by Bonatti, Diaz and Viana looks great and I had not heard of it before. A question on MO etiquette - if I find an answer very satisfactory, but more replies would still be welcome, should I flair the answer as accepted anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not the type of dynamical system in which you are interested, but
an interesting example:

> Schwartz, Richard Evan. "The Farthest Point Map on the Regular Octahedron." *Experimental Mathematics* (2021): 1-12.
> Preliminary version: [arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.11852).

The farthest point map associates to each point $p$ on the surface
the set of points $\mathcal{F}_p$ that are furthest from $p$, with distance
measured by shortest paths (geodesics segments).
Of special interest are the points $p$ for which $\mathcal{F}_p$
is a single point.
Even on the regular octahedron, the dynamics are quite intricate, but
calculable.

[image: SchwartzVorDiag]

Comment: Would this be in general a multi-valued map? Or is it a.e. single valued with respect to some suitable measure?

Comment: Schwarz restricts it to those points that do have a unique furthest point. He says, "One focus [in the literature] has been on Steinhaus's conjecture concerning the ubiquity of points $p$  such that $\mathcal{F}_p$ is a single point."